# Why do some collaborators have edit privs while others do not?

Tags: collaboration, google-classic-sites

I have created a small site using google-sites, and I listed a handful of people as collaborators.  Some of them have gmail accounts, while some don't.  I would understand it if only the users with gmail accounts were able to edit, but that is not the case.  Some users can, and some can't. but some gmail users can, and some gmail users cannot.

Should I be focusing on the user, the browser they are using, or is there somewhere else I should look to troubleshoot this?

Does it sound like user error?  I have asked them if they see the EDIT button at the top right, and they say no edit buttons of any kind appear.

EDIT: In researching this, it appears that sometimes it is related to the difference between google apps accounts and gmail accounts.  Can anyone add anything to that possibility?

Comment: just to make it clear: based on the tags you are using .. your question is about google-sites and you "created a small site" WITH GOOGLE SITE, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: I'd post the site, but since no one here is a collaborator, it would not make it any easier to test or troubleshoot.

Comment: When they say they can't see the edit button, are you _sure_ it's actually not there, or are they just being unobservant? I would double-check the permissions you've set and make sure the collaborators are all set to have full permissions.

Comment: By the way, I should have added that I already scrolled through Google's help pages, including the forums, and several other people have the same problem but no one seems to have the solution.  As to @nhinkle, there are no permissions to set.  They are either owners or collaborators or viewers, and I set them to collaborators, which is supposed to allow editing.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, are you sure all of the collaborators logged in to their Google account, that they are using the same account you added if they have more than one, and that they have cookies enabled?

Comment: Yes, they logged into their google account because they opened the site via an invitation to their gmail account, which implies they were logged in.  No, I am not sure about cookies or multiple accounts.  I can ask.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, I think issues arise when users log in using the Gmail account when they should be using their Google Apps account.

There is a handy link that you can send them that will help them troubleshoot this kind of issue.

http://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-troubleshooters/accessing-editing